# Parsing output of org-element-parse-buffer replaces each node's :parent value with modified copy of parent node

Tags: org-mode, org-properties, org-element

**As the title says,** parsing the output of org-element-parse-buffer replaces each node's :parent value with modified copy of parent node.

#### Steps to Reproduce

Here is my Org file:

```plaintext
* Milk - 2% :food:
:PROPERTIES:
:QUANTITY_CACHE: 1
:END:
* Milk - 1% :food:
* Chicken :food:
* Broccoli :food:
```

When I run `(org-element-parse-buffer 'headline)` on this file (in Org Mode, I get a reasonable AST result (comments added after):

```el
(org-data
 (:standard-properties
  [1 1 1 75 75 0 nil org-data headline nil nil 3 75 nil #<buffer Foods.org> nil nil nil]
  :path "/file/path/Foods.org" :CATEGORY "Foods")
;; Headline 1: Milk - 2%
 (headline
  (;; Headline 1 standard properties
   :standard-properties 
   [1 1 20 58 58 0 (:title) first-section headline nil nil nil nil 1 #<buffer Foods.org> nil nil #0] ;; NOTE: #0
   ;; Headline 1 properties
   :pre-blank 0 :raw-value "Milk - 2%" :title "Milk - 2%" :level 1 :priority nil :tags ("food")
   :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :QUANTITY_CACHE "1"))
;; Headline 1: Chicken
 (headline
  (;; Headline 2 standard properties
   :standard-properties
   [58 58 nil nil 75 0 (:title) nil headline nil nil nil nil 1 #<buffer Foods.org> nil nil #0] ;; NOTE: #0
   ;; Headline 2 properties
   :pre-blank 0 :raw-value "Chicken" :title "Chicken" :level 1 :priority nil :tags ("food")
   :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil)))
```

**Goal:** I eventually would like to extract, for a given (unique) title, the `(headline ...)` with that title. At the moment, I am trying to get the headline nodes into their own list so I can loop through them and search each title.

**Parsing output:** I figured I could just do `(cddr (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline)` to get a list of the headline nodes (i.e. pop the `org-data` and `(:standard-properties [...] :path "..." :CATEGORY "...")` nodes).

**However,** when I eval `(cddr (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline)`, I get the following:

```el
((headline
  ;; Standard properties of Headline 1
  (:standard-properties
   [ 1 1 20 58 58 0 (:title) first-section headline nil nil nil nil 1 #<buffer Foods.org> nil nil
       ;; NOTE: #0 replaced by the following list:
       (org-data
        (:standard-properties ;; NOTE: Standard properties of org-data (i.e. parent node)
         [1 1 1 75 75 0 nil org-data headline nil nil 3 75 nil #<buffer Foods.org> nil nil nil]
         :path "/file/path/Foods.org" :CATEGORY "Foods")
        #1
        (headline
         (:standard-properties ;; NOTE: Standard properties of Headline 2
          [58 58 nil nil 75 0 (:title) nil headline nil nil nil nil 1 #<buffer Foods.org> nil nil #4]
          :pre-blank 0 :raw-value "Chicken" :title "Chicken" :level 1 :priority nil :tags ("food")
          :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil)))
   ]
   ;; Properties of Headline 1
   :pre-blank 0 :raw-value "Milk - 2%" :title "Milk - 2%" :level 1 :priority nil :tags ("food")
   :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :QUANTITY_CACHE "1"))
 (headline
  ;; Standard properties of Headline 2
  (:standard-properties
   [58 58 nil nil 75 0 (:title) nil headline nil nil nil nil 1 #<buffer Foods.org> nil nil
       ;; NOTE: #0 replaced by the following list:
       (org-data
        (:standard-properties ;; NOTE: Standard properties of org-data (i.e. parent node)
         [1 1 1 75 75 0 nil org-data headline nil nil 3 75 nil #<buffer Foods.org> nil nil nil]
         :path "/home/user/nextcloud-sync.bak/projects/degOrge/Foods.org" :CATEGORY "Foods")
        (headline
         (:standard-properties ;; NOTE: Standard properties of Headline 1
          [1 1 20 58 58 0 (:title) first-section headline nil nil nil nil 1 #<buffer Foods.org> nil nil #4]
          :pre-blank 0 :raw-value "Milk - 2%" :title "Milk - 2%" :level 1 :priority nil :tags ("food")
          :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :QUANTITY_CACHE "1"))
        #1)
   ]
   ;; Properties of Headline 2
   :pre-blank 0 :raw-value "Chicken" :title "Chicken" :level 1 :priority nil :tags ("food")
   :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil)))
```

#### The "Replacement" Problem

As indicated by the comments, running `(cddr ...)` seems to have resulted in a replacement the `#0` value of the `:parent` property of `:standard-properties` by the `org-data` node, i.e. the parent node, i.e. the entire AST. In the inserted copy of the AST, however, the node of the current headline is replaced by `#1`.

Obviously, `cddr` is not causing this replacement. **So what is causing this replacement?**

#### Org Version 9.7 has new AST parser?

Running the command in `emacs -Q` results in an expected AST, though its structure is different; running `cddr` on that AST results in the expected output. Indeed, `emacs -Q` uses Org version `9.6.6`, while my private Org version is `9.7 (9.7-??-e90a8a69a @ /home/user/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-29.1/org/)` (Doom Emacs).

Checking the Org Mode News at `https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/org.html` reveals that

> **** Internal structure of Org parse tree has been changed
>
> The code relying upon the previously used =(TYPE PROPERTIES-PLIST CONTENTS-LIST)=
> structure may no longer work.  Please use ~org-element-create~,
> ~org-element-property~, and other Org element API functions to work
> with Org syntax trees.
>
> Some syntax node properties are no longer stored as property list elements.
> Instead, they are kept in a special vector value of a new
> =:standard-properties= property.  This is done to improve performance.
>
> If there is a need to traverse all the node properties, a new API
> function ~org-element-properties-map~ can be used.

**Logical question:** how could a change to the AST structure cause the replacement problem described above? Shouldn't the output of `(org-element-parse-buffer)` be static data? Shouldn't `cddr` operate on it without causing some changing in the underlying data structure?

The Org Mode News snippet quoted above states that "code relying upon the previously used =(TYPE PROPERTIES-PLIST CONTENTS-LIST)= structure may no longer work". However, I'm not aware that `org-element-parse-buffer` in any way depends on this structure. Also, there is no new parser, e.g. `org-element-parse-buffer-with-standard-properties`, included in the Org Mode 9.7 version of `org-element-ast.el`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info